# Spring Integration application deployment fails when deploy war to weblogic version (weblogic 12.2.1.3)

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c, jackson-databind

Application runs fine on IDE as well as when I run it as jar
Exception occurs when I deploy the application on weblogic server.

I have even tried to exclude spring-starter-json and replace it with gson but I get the same issue.

Here is the stacktrace

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)

  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }

  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Why do you need WebLogic?  You should deploy an executable JAR if you use it locally.  Deploying a Spring Boot app to a Java EE app server requires that you package it as a WAR file, but there's no reason to do so.  Spring Boot just needs an executable JAR.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Integration. Please, be more specific when you ask questions. It looks like you mess us WebLogic classpath somehow with your Jackson dependencies. Perhaps you need to play with parent-child classloader on WebLogic somehow. It always was a problem on these EE servers that they dictate you what libs has to be used even if they are outdated.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo, deployment platform has been set by my company.

Comment: Thanks   @ArtemBilan for pointing me to where to look for a solution, I Succeeded by following this article 
https://o7planning.org/11901/deploy-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server
Thanks Again.

Comment: Good. Feel free to add an answer to your own question to help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution from reading this article (https://o7planning.org/11901/deploy-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server) , It seems weblogic loads some library (com.fastxml.*) which are outdated and are incompactible with current version of spring boot.